# Propel ORM: Changing connection settings for diff and migrate

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant, propel, propel2

So I'm currently developing a little project using Propel ORM (v2.00-dev), and I figured I'd try using Vagrant for the first time.

I've set up the vagrant server to allow external MySQL connections, and built the following config file, so I don't have to ssh into the server every time I want to run propel from the command line

```
{
  "propel": {
      "paths": {
        "outputDir": "./propel/",
        "phpDir": "./propel/model/",
        "sqlDir": "./propel/sql",
        "phpConfDir": "./propel/conf"
      },
      "database": {
        "connections": {
          "project-local": {
            "adapter": "mysql",
            "dsn": "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scotchbox",
            "user": "root",
            "password": "root",
            "attributes": []
          },
          "project-remote": {
            "adapter": "mysql",
            "dsn": "mysql:host=192.168.33.10;dbname=scotchbox",
            "user": "root",
            "password": "root",
            "attributes": []
          }
        }
      },
      "runtime": {
        "defaultConnection": "project-local",
        "connections": ["projeect-local","project-remote"]
      },
      "generator": {
        "defaultConnection": "project-remote",
        "connections": ["project-remote","project-local"]
      }
    }
  }
```

paired with a `schema.xml` like:

```
<database name="project-remote">
    <!-- lots of tables in here -->
</database>
```

Now this has been working great so far. The application runs using `project-local`, and when I run propel from the command line it switches to `project-remote` as expected.

When I try and run `propel diff` however, I get the following error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This suggests that when running diffs, Propel is trying to use the `runtime` connection settings rather than the `generator` ones. Is there a way I can change this? I've checked the configuration docs, and I cant see anything about setting a connection.

I've also noticed that the `diff` command has a `--connection` argument, but I can't find any info on it, nor can I work out how to use it. I've tried:

```
propel diff --connection=project-remote
```

and

```
propel diff --connection="project-remote"
```

Both of which result in the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The path "propel.database.connections..adapter" cannot contain an empty value, but got "".
```

So, does anyone have any ideas on how to specify a connection for propel diff (and probably migrate)?

Comment: `propel diff --help`
 `Connection to use. Example: 'bookstore=mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;user=root;password=foobar' where "bookstore" is your propel database name (used in your schema.xml) (multiple values allowed)`

Connections are used for fully qualified dsn

Comment: Oh, I see. Passing the dsn every time isn't very convenient, but it does work, which is good enough for me! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can still define runtime as well as generator connections, that way you don't have to pass/specify a connection everytime you run a propel command